# How to know whether a package is automatically or manually installed

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Is there an `apt-cache`, `dpkg`, or `apt` command that can show whether a particular package is "automatic" or "manual"? `dpkg -s <package>` is able to show me whether or not a particular package is installed, but it does not say whether the package is automatically or manually installed.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `apt-mark` command. Specifically `apt-mark showauto` and `apt-mark showmanual`.

For example:

```bash
alan@ziggy:~$ apt-mark showauto | head
amd64-microcode
apparmor
attr
bash-completion
bind9-dnsutils
bind9-host
bind9-libs
binfmt-support
binutils
binutils-common
```

```bash
alan@ziggy:~$ apt-mark showmanual | head
accountsservice
acl
acpid
adduser
adwaita-icon-theme
aha
aisleriot
alsa-base
alsa-topology-conf
alsa-ucm-conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the command

```
apt show <packagename> 2>/dev/null | grep "APT-Manual-Installed"
```